# Detecting a loop in linked lists.

Tags: linked-list

I know that in order to find a loop in a linked list I can define two references to the list and move them at different speeds. Move one forward by 1 node and the other by 2 nodes.

So if the linked list has a loop they will definitely meet,
else either of the two references(or their next) will become null.

My question is : why the other reference should be moved in 2 nodes 
why it cant be moved by any other even/odd number, is the correctness of the solution 
relies on this ?

Thanks in advnance.

Comment: This question has already been asked here, but I'm having trouble finding it.  You can indeed take steps of size 3, 4, 5, 6, ..., etc. and the algorithm will still work, but it will take a longer time to converge.

Answer (score 0):

The larger the step, the more times around the loop before they are guaranteed to meet.

Comment: Thanks.
So what are you saying that it can be any other number but most efficient is 2?